# <a> indentation produces whitespace

Tags: html, hyperlink, icons, whitespace

I'm trying to display two links. But when I use the correct indentation the second link renders whitespace in front of the icon. Why does this happen? And is there a way to prevent it without using hardly readable code?

Creates whitespace:

```
<a href="...">
    <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-lg"/>
</a>
<a href="...">
    <i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg"/>
</a>
```

[image: Second link produces whitespace]

Creates no whitespace:

```
<a href="...">
    <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-lg"/>
</a>
<a href="..."><i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg"/></a>
```

[image: Second link produces no whitespace here]

Comment: I only see one image so hard to see the difference... Did you look at the difference client-side in the html? Amnything that can explain it there?

Comment: @Kukeltje I added the second image. I did look at the html code rendered by the browser, but the only difference I can spot is the `i` tag being on the next line like in the source code.

Comment: Tried a `h:commandLink` too? Indentation with tabs? spaces? Mixes?

Comment: This is not a JSF problem. This is a HTML problem. JSF is in the context of your question merely a HTML code generator. You'd have had exactly the same problem when using plain vanilla HTML instead of some HTML generator. Therefore I've reduced down the irrelevant JSF noise to make the question better understandable and answerable by HTML users.